# Prove that the Area of triangle whose vertices are $(0,0)$, $(b,a)$ and $(x,y)$ is $|by-ax|/2$

Tags: geometry, number-theory

Prove that the Are of triangle whose vertices are $(0,0)$, $(b,a)$ and $(x,y)$ is $\displaystyle \frac{|by-ax|}{2}$.

I found this problem in Number theory by George Andrews, but I wonder how it related with Number theory?

Anyone has idea so prove this problem?

Comment: I would begin with the case that the points $(b,a)$ and $(x,y)$ lie in the first quadrant, for the sake of simplicity, and compute the area of your triangle as half the area of a parallelogram.  The area of the parallelogram is the determinant of a certain $2\times 2$ matrix, as appears in your expression, but if this is not already known, it may be derived geometrically.

Comment: oops thank for idea and answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about number theory, but I can show using some simple algebra and geometry. Let's call our coordinate system $\alpha$ along the first axis and $\beta$ along the second axis. The equation of the line that goes through $(b,a)$ and $(x,y)$ has the form $\beta=m \alpha +n$. We plug in the two points, so $a=m b +n$ and $y=m x+n$. From these two $m=(a-y)/(b-x)$ and $n=a-mb$. The reason to calculate this equation is to see where it intersects the $\alpha$ axis. We plug in $\beta=0$ and we get $\alpha=(ax-by)/(a-y)$. Now, for simplicity, call $O=(0,0)$, $A=(b,a)$, $B=(x,y)$, and $C=((ax-by)/(a-y),0)$. The area of the triangle $AOB$ plus the area area of $BOC$ is equal to area of $AOC$. The base is $OC$ with length $(ax-by)/(a-y)$. The height in $AOC$ is $a$, and in $BOC$ is y, so you get the area as $|1/2(ax-by)/(a-y)*(a-y)|$ which is exactly what you were looking for